# jQuery UI confirmation dialog - manipulating output

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I need to modify the dialog confirmation buttons. I want to have the confirm and cancel buttons swapped around (so cancel is to the right not the left of the confirm button). I also want to change the background image on the confirm button so that it's a different colour. I thought about doing this in seperate jQuery code so that I don't have to dig into the UI code and modify it. First of all can this be done?

Secondly if I grab the div with the css class 'ui-dialog-buttonpane' as my selector. Which is the div surrounding the button controls. How can I select JUST the confirm button? Is there a way I can say I want a child control of type button that contains the text 'confirm'?

TIA

Lloyd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) order the buttons in the dialog settings in the order you wish them to appear.

2) `$('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').children('button')[1]`